# How to add Custom value in timeFormat d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data set with dates specified as `date`

```
Q3 1954
Q4 1954
Q1 1955
Q2 1955
Q3 1955
Q4 1955
Q3 1955
Q4 1955
Q1 1956
```

I wanted this to be on the x-axis and with data points corresponding to each dates.

Is there a timeFormat to specify such kind of dates series into axis in D3 v4 ?

Comment: I think this is very close to what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471224/how-to-format-time-on-xaxis-use-d3-js

Comment: I would add %Y inside the timeFormat function to get the year but am not sure which format specifiers to use for getting "Qn".

Comment: For that you could do something like 
`.tickFormat(function(d){return "any thing" + d3.time.format("%Y")(d)});`

Comment: I have posted answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out using `scaleBand()` could solve this issue.

code snippet for this axis is

```
 var width = 800, height = 800;

var ydata = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

var xaxis  = d3.scaleBand()
                .rangeRound([0, width])
                .padding(1);

d3.csv("static/date.csv", function(data){
        xaxis.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }))

        var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
                        .scale(xaxis);

        var xAxisTranslate = height/2 + 10;

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(50, " + xAxisTranslate  +")")
        .call(x_axis)
});

var yscale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(ydata)])
               .range([height/2, 0]);

var y_axis = d3.axisLeft()
               .scale(yscale);

svg.append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(50, 10)")
   .call(y_axis);
```

[image]

I also found the documentation from [enter link description here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/#ordinal)

Thanks @Cyril for time.