# Add additional scale parallel to x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

(Not sure if `scale` is the correct word here.) I want to add additional scale `(Ep1 CHL, Ep2 WHO, ..)` parallel to x-axis as in the snapshot below:
[image]

How do I achieve this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SKb8W/11/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [**`fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/SKb8W/12/) for your requirement.

And another [**`post`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226576/creating-a-text-labeled-x-axis-with-an-ordinal-scale-in-d3-js) for your brief explanation.

Added a column named `label` and the axis parallel axis is created.

**Step 1** : Define the `d3.scale.ordinal()` and get the unique values using `d3.map()`.

```
var x2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .domain(data.map(function (d) {return d.label; }))
 .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.05);
```

**Step 2** : Pass the scale created to `d3.svg.axis()`.

```
var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x2)
.orient("bottom")
```

**Step 3** : Append a `g` for the new axis and call the axis created.

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
//.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis2)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for the fiddle! But, I would like the new ordinal scale to synchronize with the scale on x-axis. How do I do that?

Comment: [**`Here`**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilS/3hgra/) you have the answer. You need to change the entire line statements as per this fiddle. Then you can of course have the `date` and `labels` to be on the same line.

Comment: Sorry, your fiddle did not get updated in the comment.

Comment: Which line statements do I need to change exactly? Sorry, I am new to D3.

Comment: But I see that you already used `.rangeRoundBands()`. I am confused.

Comment: `rangeBands` are used for ordinal scale. And the date axis is not created by ordinal scale. It's been created using time scale. I haven't done this before 2 scales in a graph. One ordinal and one time scale. I need to find it out too.

Comment: I achieved it using `.rangePoints()` http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/SKb8W/26/ line # 60. All thanks to @Oleg

Comment: Great. I got something new :)